# Draw the arc of a ball

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, physics

Draw the parabolic trajectory of a thrown ball.

The input is the ball's initial upward velocity, a positive integer `v`. Every second, the ball moves `1` space right and `v` spaces vertically, and then `v` decreases by `1` to due to gravity. So, the upward velocity eventually steps down from `v` to `0` and down to `-v`, finally falling back down to its initial height.

The ball's positions trace a parabola. At horizontal position `x`, its height is `y=x*(2*v+1-x)/2`, with `(0,0)` the ball's initial position at the bottom left.

Output ASCII art of the ball's trajectory with `O`'s on the coordinates it ever occupies. The output should be a single multi-line piece of text, not an animation of the path over time.

The output should have no leading newlines and at most one trailing newline.  The bottom line should be flush with the left edge of the screen, i.e. have no extra leading spaces. Trailing spaces are OK. You may assume the output line width fits in the output terminal.

v=1

```
 OO 
O  O
```

v=2

```
  OO  
 O  O 

O    O
```

v=3

```
   OO   
  O  O  

 O    O 


O      O
```

v=4

```
    OO    
   O  O   

  O    O  


 O      O 



O        O
```

v=10

```
          OO          
         O  O         

        O    O        


       O      O       



      O        O      




     O          O     





    O            O    






   O              O   







  O                O  








 O                  O 









O                    O
```

Related: [Bouncing ball simulation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/10520/20260)

---

**Leaderboard:**

```js
var QUESTION_ID=111861,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/111861/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Can we ouput a list of lines?

Comment: @Riker Nope, string with newlines.

Comment: loosely related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/110410

Comment: Do I only need to account for V > 0?

Comment: Yes, v will be positive.

Comment: Wow, middle-school-math-that-I-didn't-listen-to-that-much-so-I-don't-like-them-but-whatever-:P

Answer (score 17):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>18</s> <s>16</s> 13 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil)!

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ«←OＭ⊕ι↓»‖Ｃ
```

### Explanation

```
Ｆ⊕Ｎ«        »    For ι (implicitly from 0) to (1 + input as number)
       ←O          Print O, with print direction rotated 180 degrees
         Ｍ⊕ι↓     Move 1+ ι units down
               
                ‖Ｃ Reflect (in the default direction, right), leaving original intact
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/charcoal#ASwA0///77ym4oCmwrfCueKBuu@8rsK5wqtP77ytzrnihpPCu@KAlu@8o@KGkP//NQ) Link is to verbose code.

Comment: I like this one a lot, +1; Also OP's output uses uppercase "O". (Not that it matters at all lol)

Comment: If you use `↘O` then you can loop from 0 to N inclusive instead which saves you two bytes immediately.

Comment: @Neil Thanks! Also, this is a very old post :P (and I wonder if I should be using newer features. Probably not?)

Comment: Strictly speaking I've only saved you 1 byte so far as the other two bytes were you replacing `⁺¹` with `⊕`. However now that you've moved the `←` from the `‖Ｃ` to the `O` you can save another byte by writing `↙OＭι↓`, so I'm back up to a two byte saving again.

Comment: Also you forgot to update your TIO link. And technically I believe we now allow newer features, but I can't claim credit for those bytes.

Answer (score 6):

## C, <s>93</s> 92

(Note, someone got to 87 in the comments)

```c
y,n;f(s){for(y=0;y<=s;){printf("%*c%*c",s-y+1,79,y*2+1,79);for(n=++y;s+1-n&&n--;)puts("");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#HYyxCsMgFAD3fIUIDb6oYLqU8OrHBIk0Q1@CmkHEz@5sbeGGW@5aVoReRCj@CCJbg/lpI0I5w07JC36bXIerqLOc1WNRebr/BfBXkJUyY5SzpnEkrRHOK0XBOWCtrS/Ye91JQBkY82I2gF3Clq5AzOBQ24cO7Vb32r4)

---

Readable:

```c
y,n;f(s){
    for(y=0;y<=s;){
        printf("%*c%*c",s-y+1,79,y*2+1,79);
        for(n=++y;s+1-n&&n--;)puts("");
    }
}
```

---

Notes:

I can collapse both for loops into just one for loop by iterating the total number of lines outputted, which is given by the formula: `n*-~n/2+1`

```c
y,n,r;f(s){
    for(r=s,y=n=0;r<s*-~s/2+1;)
        y==n?printf("%*c%*c",s-y+1,79,y*2+1,79),y=0,++n:r++,y++,puts("");
}
```

But it ends up being even more bytes than just using two seperate for-loops

Comment: You can save one byte by incrementing `s` at the beginning, like this: `y,n;f(s){++s;for(y=0;y<s;){printf("%*c%*c",s-y,79,y*2+1,79);for(n=++y;s-n&&n--;)puts("");}}`

Comment: @Steadybox won't compile for me. Also I got 90 bytes when I counted that (after removing whitespace characters)

Comment: All I did was adding the `++s;` at the beginning and then changing `y<=s` to `y<s` and `s-y+1` to `s-y` and `s+1-n` to `s-n`, so it should compile (and should be 91 bytes).

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with the encoding of the code block in my comment. Copying and pasting the code from the comment won't compile for me either.

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsIwEEX3PUUMWGZMBupKZOxhJBjpwrFk0sVQ6tVjCx/ee4uf6J1SaxaFMyiu@VvAxlMIyvZQxqPnMknN4M@XtM9HJYu3ezT6HcQoYwjGStL3QsQ4L1XBe@St7Uf3eU4CuHbOZbgOyLuUV12KuIG7rf0B "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ceilingcat Another great one, well done!

Answer (score 5):

## GNU sed, 41

- Score includes +1 from `-r` flags to sed.

```
s/$/OO/
:
s/(\s*) O( *)O$/&\n\1O \2 O/
t
```

Input is in unary, as a string of spaces - the length of string is the input.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#HclBDsIgEEbhPaf4FygtiUFqVzaeYS4wO6Gxm8EwDSvvjk3f7stbS0XDJoiY8MCMeF@QisFRfn8K2su2U9@6yb7CXbyyONiGHzQn3Cpc12ADUTBPo2Fg9SNogB/JhisLRwJPOPbenUlFcv8D).

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x=0:(n and f(n-1,x+1)or'')+'\n'*n+' '*x+'O'+'  '*n+'O'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJCnU2FrYKWRp5CYl6KQppGna6hToW2omV@krq6prR6Tp66Vp62uoK5Voa3urw5kKYAF/NX/FxRl5pUAdRgaaP43NAAA)

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 76 bytes

```
x=input()
for i in range(x):print' '*(x-i),'O'+' '*i*2+'O'+'\n'*(i-x+1and i)
```

Pretty simple. The `i-x+1and i` is to prevent a bunch of trailing newlines.

Comment: Moving the newline to the beginning of the print, like `'\n'*(i-1)`saves 7 bytes while avoiding the trailing newlines.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
Q:tqYsQ79Z?PtPv!c
```

Try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=Q%3AtqYsQ79Z%3FPtPv%21c&inputs=4&version=19.8.0) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/gfaFVSGFkcaG4ZZR9QElCmmPzfJeS/IZcRlzGXCZehAQA).

#### Explanation

```
Q        % Implicitly input v. Add 1
:        % Push [1 2 ... v+1]
tq       % Duplicate and subtract 1: pushes [0 1 ... v]]
Ys       % Cumulative sum: gives [0 1 3 6 ...]
Q        % Add 1: gives [1 2 4 7 ...]
79       % Push 79 (ASCII for 'O')
Z?       % Create sparse matrix from column indices [1 2 3 4 ...],
         % row indices [1 2 4 7 ...], and data 79
P        % Flip vertically
tP       % Duplicate, flip vertically
v        % Concatenate the two matrices vertically
!        % Transpose
c        % Convert to char. Implicitly display. Char 0 is shown as space
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to *Adnan*

```
ƒ¶N×'ONúRÂJ}.c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39s0qFtfoenq/v7Hd4VdLjJq1Yv@f9/QwMA)

**Explanation**

```
ƒ                   # for N in [0 ... input]
 ¶N×                # push N newlines
    'O              # push "O"
      Nú            # pad with N spaces in front
        RÂ          # reverese and create a reversed copy
          J         # join everything to a string
           }        # end loop
            .c      # pad lines until centered
```

Comment: For 14 bytes: `ƒ¶N×'ONúRÂJ}.c` :)

Comment: @Adnan Thanks! I tried `.c` with a different version, but it didn't work well then. Forgot about trying it with this one and complete forgot that `ú` exists :)

Comment: Definitely better than the zip method I chose, interesting approach vertically.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>98</s> <s>92</s> <s>89</s> <s>84</s> 78 bytes

*(-20 bytes thanks to Arnauld!)*

```
f=(v,i=0)=>i>v?"":" "[r="repeat"](v-i)+0+" "[r](2*i)+0+`
`[r](i++<v&&i)+f(v,i)
```

A recursive solution. This is also my first *ever* answer in JavaScript, so please be gentle! I am still learning all this neat language has to offer, so golfing tips are very much appreciated. :)

### Test Snippet

You may need to scroll to see the entire output.

```js
f=(v,i=0)=>i>v?"":" "[r="repeat"](v-i)+0+" "[r](2*i)+0+`
`[r](i++<v&&i)+f(v,i)
```

```html
<input id=i min=1 type=number><button onclick=alert(f(document.getElementById("i").value))>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Also, including variables inside backtick strings with `${}` only saves bytes when the variable part is surrounded by static parts. As such, these strings should always start and end with static parts.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for all the tips! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the advice. That will come in handy. :)

Comment: You can safely use `0` instead of `"0"`. They'll be coerced to strings. And on second thought: `i++<v&&i` is actually one byte shorter than `(i<v)*++i`.

Comment: @Arnauld Thank you once again! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Happy JS golfing!

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 76 bytes

```bash
for((n=$1+1;--n;));{
yes ''|head -$n
r=$r›${n}AO
t=›${n}BO$t
}
echo O${r}O$t
```

Only works in a terminal since it uses [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). `›` represents the CSI byte (**0x9b**).

#### Test run

```bash
$ # The terminal's encoding must be set to ISO-8859-1.
$
$ xxd -g 1 arc.sh
0000000: 66 6f 72 28 28 6e 3d 24 31 2b 31 3b 2d 2d 6e 3b  for((n=$1+1;--n;
0000010: 29 29 3b 7b 0a 79 65 73 20 27 27 7c 68 65 61 64  ));{.yes ''|head
0000020: 20 2d 24 6e 0a 72 3d 24 72 9b 24 7b 6e 7d 41 4f   -$n.r=$r.${n}AO
0000030: 0a 74 3d 9b 24 7b 6e 7d 42 4f 24 74 0a 7d 0a 65  .t=.${n}BO$t.}.e
0000040: 63 68 6f 20 4f 24 7b 72 7d 4f 24 74              cho O${r}O$t
$
$ bash arc.sh 1
 OO
O  O
$ bash arc.sh 2
  OO
 O  O

O    O
$ bash arc.sh 3
   OO
  O  O

 O    O


O      O
$ bash arc.sh 4
    OO
   O  O

  O    O


 O      O



O        O
```

Comment: You can use `sed $nq` to save a byte.

Comment: Sadly, no. I'd have to use `sed ${n}q` which is longer.

Comment: Argh, I see, you can do `sed $n\q` instead, but that does not make much sense either, as it would be the same byte count as `head` !

Comment: Suggest `((n=$1;n;--n))` for -1 byte

Answer (score 3):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 37 bytes

```
x=0xR{y@xy-` *`o` y2**`o...2y{[` };};
```

Getting in with my kind-of-golfy language before the proper golfy langauges jump in.

### Explained

```
x=              # Set 'x' to the input
0xR{            # For everything between the input and 0
    y@          # Set the iteration value to y, for this function only.
    xy-` *      # Subtract y from x, repeat the string " " that many times.
    `o          # Push an "o" to the stack.
    ` y2**      # Push 2*y " "'s to the stack
    `o          # Push another "o" to the stack
    ...         # Concatenate the parts of this string together, giving us the two balls.
    2y{[` };    # For all numbers between 2 and y, add a newline.
};              #
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn-2#@19ha1ARVF3pUFGpm6CglZCfoFBppAWk9fT0jCqroxMUaq1rrf///28OAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Retina, 35

- 2 bytes saved thanks to @MartinEnder

Port of [my sed answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111866/11259):

```
.+
$* OO
+`(\s*) (O *)O$
$&¶$1O $2 O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ivp82loqXg78@lnaARU6ylqaDhr6Cl6a/CpaJ2aJuKoYqRgoL//@AElf@GXEZcxlwmXIYGAA).

Answer (score 3):

### Retina, <s>29</s> 19 bytes

```
 ?
$.`$*¶$&$'O$`$`O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@69gz6Wil6CidWibipqKur9KgkqC////CiAAAA)

Takes input in unary as a run of spaces. Port of my JavaScript answer. Edit: Saved 10 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder♦.

Comment: I´m only waiting for someone to come up with a Retina spin off called Retsina.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 89 bytes

```
a=2*v+3
x=matrix(" ",a,v^2+1)
for(k in 0:v)x[c(1-k,k+2)+v,k^2+1]="o"
x[a,]="\n"
cat(x,sep="")
```

- Create a matrix of spaces (the variable a is the width of this matrix, saving a couple of bytes)
- Fill in "o"s at the required locations, working from the top of the arc downwards and outwards
- Add a newline at the end of each matrix row
- Collapse the matrix down to a single string and print

This is my first attempt at golfing, comments welcome...

Answer (score 3):

## [Röda](http://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```
f n{seq 0,n|{|i|["
"*i," "*(n-i),"O"," "*i*2,"O"]}_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#@5@mkFddnFqoYKCTV1Ndk1kTrcSlpJWpo6SgpKWRp5upqaPkrwTmZWoZgdixtfG1/3MTM/MUqrk40zRMNblq/wMA)

Usage: `main { f(5) }`

Ungolfed version:

```
function f(n) {
    seq(0, n) | for i do
        push("\n"*i, " "*(n-i), "O", " "*i*2, "O")
    done
}
```

Comment: Can you use a literal newline instead of `\n` and save 1 byte?

Comment: @KritixiLithos That works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, <s>75</s> 73 bytes

```
<vp00:&
1<-1_:v#\+55:g01\-g01g00" O"1\*2g01" O"1p0
#@_\:v>$$:!
1\,:\_^#:-
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=PHZwMDA6JgoxPC0xXzp2I1wrNTU6ZzAxXC1nMDFnMDAiIE8iMVwqMmcwMSIgTyIxcDAKI0BfXDp2PiQkOiEKMVwsOlxfXiM6LQ&input=NA)

The first line reads in the velocity, *v*, and saves a copy in memory. The second line then counts down from *v* to zero, with the index *i*, and on each iteration pushes a sequence of character/length pairs onto the stack.

```
Length  Character
-----------------
1       'O'
i*2     ' '
1       'O'
v-i     ' '
i       LINEFEED
```

This sequence represents a kind of run-length encoding of the required output in reverse. The last two lines then simply pop these character/length pairs off the stack, outputting *length* occurrences of each *character*, until the stack is empty.

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>129</s> <s>124</s> 109 bytes

Golfed:

```java
v->{String s="",t="";for(int j,y=0;y<=v;++y){for(j=0;j<v;++j)s+=j<y?"\n":" ";s+="o"+t+"o";t+="  ";}return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jZFBT4QwEIXv/IqXniCsRC8ehF2zxph48rDe1ENFupZ0C2lLDTH89nVgAdF4sJdp@r6@N5k51s2rkjlyxa3FreEfj@/F1uQPYnvDlcJnEAAjYx13VHwl33DgUoc7Z6TeP72Am72NiAUdURmEUjtIrHGRUslwmSKO5UQAu9a64pBUjUtqsnBKhyL0ONvMBDGDOSy5MLaCG2o6y3NMuUJL2nlKJVvD91FttDAa2fIEldTOwJQ/GVBSvO6xjIyuwZ41wxUYWJQusC749YFVDDF1F/e3JekGFVg8fn82hWuMhp20DivIaE76Yz7/0Hr7btiXkZ67YlrYOEkRltzzpHFSJaLRuZOVTu61uxvv2YnbQFAvNFg/DWhsViS8rlUb@iGuC7rgePwC)

Ungolfed:

```java
public class DrawTheArcOfABall {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
      System.out.println(f(v -> {
        String s = "", t = "";
        for (int j, y = 0; y <= v; ++y) {
          for (j = 0; j < v; ++j) {
            s += (j < y ? "\n" : " ");
          }
          s += "o" + t + "o";
          t += "  ";
        }
        return s;
      } , i));
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  private static String f(java.util.function.IntFunction<String> f, int v) {
    return f.apply(v);
  }
}
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lZK9TsMwFIX3PMVRJ0cpESwsSSsVISQmhrIBgwlxceQ6ke0YRSjPHm7SpD9DK@rF1j3H37nWdZcpbi0eDf95/c5XJnsRqweuFH6DAKjqTyUzWMcdbb6UX9hyqdnaGak3bx/gZmND8oKWKA2Y1A4SC9wltKW4TxBFcnIA68a6fBuXtYsrQjilmWAeN8u9gzwDHJYos1myL/fkYo6GyreH6hCaUDVdwPdhTXiEGvViuIOCGmp6T3HqAWVFFPauj@KA9gKGWr6IwlnSTi9P9GuaxDXog2pyVxsNO2kt5pBhmJyfyz@0Ht8O/8RIz10@fZRxgoIV3PO4dlLFotaZk6WOn7V7Gs/pzreEmA/T9dOLx2ZFzKtKNcwPcRTUBl33Bw "Java (OpenJDK 8) – TIO Nexus")

Comment: For the second nested for loop, I think `for(;j<v;++)` would work, because at this point in time `j==y`.  Also, you could remove the third by adding a second string variable inside the main for loop `String t="";` (12) and `t+="  ";` (8) inside the first nested loop.  Then the third loop just becomes `s+="o"+t+"o";`

Comment: Also, you can combine the first two nested loops to `for(j=0;j<v;++j)s+=j<y?"\n":" ";` although I'm not sure how this meshes with my previous comment about `t`

Comment: You can initialize `t=""` alongside s in the beginning, and then add `t+="  "` each loop around after you do `s+="o"+t+"o"`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 13 bytes

```
ÝηROÂ«ð×'O«ζ»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v8wNWFiMWX//8OdzrdST8OCwqvDsMOXJ0/Cq862wrv//zI)

```
Ý                # [0..n]
 €LRO            # [0.sum(), 0..1.sum(), ..., 0..n-1.sum(), 0..n.sum()]
     Â«          # Mirror image the array [0, 0..n.sum(), 0]
       ð×'O«     # Push that many spaces with an O appended to it.
            .B   # Pad small elements with spaces to equal largest element length.
              ø» # Transpose and print.
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, <s>124</s> <s>112</s> <s>85</s> <s>88</s> <s>66</s> <s>63</s> 59 bytes

```
For i=0To[A1]:?Space([A1]-i)"O"Space(2*i)"O"String(i,vbCr):Next
```

<sub><sup>Saved 29 bytes in total thanks to Taylor Scott</sup></sub>

This must be run the in VBA Immediate window and print the result in the same.

Expanded / Formatted, it becomes:

```
For i=0 To [A1]
   Debug.Print Space([A1]-i) & "O" & Space(2*i) & "O" & String(i,vbCr)
Next
```

<sub>(It turns out that concatenation in a print command is automatic without an operator.)</sub>

Comment: `b & s &` Spaces alert!

Comment: I tried and it erred the first time. Going back, I realized it'll expand `b &s &String` but not `b&s&String`. Also, at first I thought you meant to use the `Space` function which I totally should have and that ended up saving more bytes.

Comment: You can condense `for i=0 To v` and `debug.? b` to `for i=0To v` and `Debug.?b`, respectively for `-2` bytes. And just so you know, the community consensus is that for languages with autoformatting, you may count before it is autoformatted, meaning after you make these changes you should have a byte count of 85 Bytes

Comment: On a second look, this is a snippet - not a function or subroutine; so it is not a valid solution. I believe that you could fix this by converting it an Excel VBA immediate window function and taking input from `[A1]` (`v=[A1]`) Also, I don't think you actually need the `s` variable.

Comment: @TaylorScott You're right on both points. I appreciate your continued efforts to improve the Excel and VBA answers on PPCG; I've learned much.

Comment: I did a bit of rearranging on what you made to squeeze some extra bytes out of if - give `For i=0To[A1]:?Space([A1]-i)"O"Space(2*i)"O"String(i+1,vbCr):Next` a try - 65 Bytes

Comment: @TaylorScott That seems like an obvious improvement in retrospect but I did not know that concatenation did not require an operator in the immediate window. That'll save me some bytes in the future. I did have to add a `;` to the end of the print command, though, because it kept adding an extra line break by default. Thanks!

Comment: @EngineerToast I had not noticed that when golfing it down - but I think that you may actually be able to remove the `+1` and `;` in `String(i+1,vbCr);` in order to get to the correct number of linebreaks

Comment: @TaylorScott That should have been obvious, in retrospect.

Comment: @EngineerToast OH one last thing - I always forget this - convert the `Space(...)` calls to `Spc(...)` calls for -4 Bytes; Also in the autoformatted section of your answer the compiler adds `;` after every non-terminal entry to the `?` call

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 69 bytes

```
r=replicate
f n=[0..n]>>= \a->r a '\n'++r(n-a)' '++'O':r(2*a)' '++"O"
```

Usage example: `f 3` -> `"   OO\n  O  O\n\n O    O\n\n\nO      O"`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@19kW5RakJOZnFiSypWmkGcbbaCnlxdrZ2erEJOoa1ekkKigHpOnrq1dpJGnm6iprgBkqvurWxVpGGlBuUr@Sv9zEzPzFGwVCkpLgkuKfPIUVBTSFEz@AwA).

Answer (score 2):

## MATLAB, 114 Bytes

```
function p(v),for i=0:v,fprintf([repmat(' ',1,v-i),'o',repmat(' ',1,2*i),'o',repmat('\n',1,(i*(i~=v)+1))]);end,end
```

ungolfed:

```
function p(v)
   for i=0:v
       fprintf([repmat(' ',1,v-i),'o',repmat(' ',1,2*i),'o',repmat('\n',1,(i*(i~=v)+1))]);
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>17</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘Ḷ+\Ṛ⁶ẋ;€”Om0z⁶Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYcbDHdu0Yx7unPWocdvDXd3Wj5rWPGqY659rUAUUiPz//78pAA)**

#### How?

```
‘Ḷ+\Ṛ⁶ẋ;€”Om0z⁶Y - Main link: v         e.g. 3
‘                - increment: v+1            4
 Ḷ               - lowered range             [0,1,2,3]
  +\             - reduce with addition      [0,1,3,6]
    Ṛ            - reverse                   [6,3,1,0]
     ⁶           - a space                   ' '
      ẋ          - repeat (vectorises)       ['      ','   ',' ','']
       ;€        - concatenate each with
         ”O      -     an 'O'                ['      O','   O',' O','O']
           m0    - concatenate reflection    ['      O','   O',' O','O','O','O ','O   ','O      ']
             z⁶  - transpose with space fill ['   OO   ','  O  O  ','        ',' O    O ','        ','        ','O      O']
               Y - join with line feeds      ['   OO   \n  O  O  \n        \n O    O \n        \n        \nO      O']
                 - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

```js
f=
n=>' '.repeat(n+1).replace(/./g,"$`#$'O$`$`O").replace(/ *#/g,s=>[...s].fill``.join`
`)
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 oninput=o.textContent=f(+this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Nonrecursive solution. Indexing requirement was annoying, both in the above and the following 62-byte (I don't know whether it would result in a shorter Retina port) recursive solution:

```
f=n=>~n?` `.repeat(n)+`OO`+f(n-1).replace(/^ *O/gm,`
$&  `):``
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 76 bytes

```
for(;$argn>=0;$s.="  ")echo($r=str_repeat)("
",$i++),$r(" ",$argn--),o,$s,o;
```

Run with `echo <v> | php -nR '<code>'` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/308cb432f2f510679934cd7370608ca05c5656bf).

loops `$argn` down from input to `0` and `$i` up from 0;
prints - in that order - in each iteration

- `$i` newlines (none in the first iteration)
- left padding: `$argn` spaces
- left ball: `o`
- inner padding: `2*$i` spaces
- right ball: `o`

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

```
2éoÀñYço/^2á O
HPJ>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@290eGX@4YbDGyMPL8/XjzM6vFDBn8sjwMvu////xgA)

Explain

```
2éo            " Insert two 'o's
   Àñ          " <Arg> times repeat
     Y         " Yank the current (top) line.  This is always '\s*oo'
      ço/      " On every line that matches 'o'
         ^     " Go to the first non-whitespace character (the 'o')
          2á   " Append two spaces (between the two 'o's
             O " Add a blank line on top of the current one
H              " Go to the first line
 P             " Paste in front ('\s*oo')
  J            " Join this line with the blank line immediately after it
   >           " Indent once
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 48 bytes

**47 bytes code + 1 for `-n`.**

```perl
$_++;print$/x$-,$"x$_,O,$"x($-++*2),O while$_--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXlvbuqAoM69ERb9CRVdHRalCJV7HH0RrqOhqa2sZaer4K5RnZOakqsTr6v7/b/ovv6AkMz@v@L9uHgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 17 bytes

```
r{n*íï- *'oï *+_x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7@oOk/r8NrD63UVtNTzD69X0NKOr/j/3/Q/AA)

### Explanation

```
r                   range(0, n)
 {                  start block or arbitrary length
  n                 newline char, or map array with newlines
   *                pop a, b : push(a*b)
    í               get total number of iterations of for loop
     ï              index of current loop, or length of last loop
      -             pop a, b : push(a-b)
                    space character
        *           pop a, b : push(a*b)
         '          push single character
          o         print TOS without popping
           ï        index of current loop, or length of last loop
                    space character
             *      pop a, b : push(a*b)
              +     pop a, b : push(a+b)
               _    duplicate TOS
                x   reverse int/array/string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 29 bytes

```
[:|:@(,~|.)' O'#~1,.~i.+/\@,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61qrBw0dOpq9DTVFfzVlesMdfTqMvW09WMcdGL/a3KlJmfkK6QpGEIY6uowASN0AeP/AA)

Turned out very similar to Razetime's APL answer, though solved independently.  I tried about 3 other approaches before realizing this one would be shortest.

Answer (score 0):

## Stacked, <s>67</s> 63 bytes

```
args 0#1+:@x:>{!n x\-1-' '*'O'+n 2*' '*+'O'+x 1-n!=n*LF*+out}"!
```

Initial attempt, 67 bytes

```
args 0# :@v 1+2*:>[:v:+1+\-2/*' '*'O'+''split]"!fixshape tr rev out
```

Full program. Generates something like:

```
('O'
 ' ' 'O'
 ' ' 'O'
 'O')
```

Which is the padded, transposed, reversed, and outputted.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 163 bytes

```
@set l=@for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do @call
@set s=
%l% set s= %%s%%
@set t=
%l%:c&for /l %%j in (2,1,%%i)do @echo(
:c
@echo %s%O%t%O
@set s=%s:~1%
@set t=  %t%
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 52 bytes

```
->x{(0..x).map{|a|$><<$/*a+' '*(x-a)+?O+' '*a*2+?O}}
```

No trailing newline (allowed by the rules: "*at most one trailing newline*")

Answer (score 0):

## AHK, 93 bytes

```
m=0
n=1
f=%1%-1
Loop,%1%{
r=%r%{VK20 %f%}O{VK20 %m%}O{`n %n%}
m+=2
n++
f--
}
FileAppend,%r%,*
```

If I could figure out how to do math inside of repeating keystrokes, that'd be great.
 - `VK20` equates to a space
 - `FileAppend` outputs to `stdout` if the filename is `*`

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

```hs
n!x=[1..n]>>x
-1#i=[]
x#i=(x-1)#(i+1)++x!"\n"++i!" "++'O':(2*x)!" "++"O"
(#0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@5@nWGEbbainlxdrZ1fBpWuonGkbHctVAaQ0KnQNNZU1MrUNNbW1KxSVYvKUtLUzFZUUgJS6v7qVhpFWhSaEq@SvxJVuq6FsoPk/NzEzT8FWoSg1McUnT8HOzlahoLQkuKRIQU8h/b8JAA) Usage: `(#0) 5`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,r='O':(r*n and f(n-1,' '+r))+'\n'*n+r+'  '*n+'O'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FcsxCoAwEETRWk8x3RqzghErwTN4AZuIBAQdZfH@0XS/@C@n@YzXtkdQbZZFpsZaInJHatgFFYg357yslJbevAAl/jWn20AcRNBBRw39VFePHXyLdYpi8gc)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 26 bytes

```
VyhQ=+Y+*Zd\O=+ZQ=tQ)j_.tY
```

[Try it Online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VyhQ%3D%2BY%2B*Zd%5CO%3D%2BZQ%3DtQ%29j_.tY&input=4&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
VyhQ=+Y+*Zd\O=+ZQ=tQ)j_.tY
                            Implicit Q=input() (speed), Z=0 (position), Y=[].
VyhQ                )       For N in [0,...,2Q+2]...
       +*Zd\O               ... prepend Z spaces to 'O'...
    =+Y                     ... add that line to Y...
             =+ZQ=tQ        ... then update position and speed.
                     j_.tY  Combine the lines to form the parabola.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <sup><s>27</s></sup> 25 bytes

```apl
(⌽,⊢)⍉↑↑∘'O'¨1,1-1↓+\⍳⎕+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97b/Go569Oo@6Fmk@6u181DYRhDpmqPurH1phqGOoa/iobbJ2zKPezY/6pmobgnT8T@My5ErjMgJiYyA2AWJDAwA)

-2 bytes from kritixilithos at the APL Orchard.

-2 bytes from Adám.

### Explanation

```apl
 (⌽,⊢)⍉↑↑∘'O'¨1,1-1↓+\⍳⎕+1
                      ⍳⎕+1  range 1 - n+1
                    +\      cumulative sum over each element
                  1↓        drop the first value (0)
                1-          subtract 1 from each value
              1,            prepend 1 to it.
             ¨              for each element,
        ↑∘'O'               prepend(element-1) spaces to 'O'.
       ↑                    convert to matrix
      ⍉                     transpose
 (⌽,⊢)                      prepend its reverse (palindromize).
```